# want to display color name in my color picker android app

Tags: java, android, color-picker

```
image.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int x = (int) event.getX();

            int y = (int) event.getY();

            final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

            redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            greenValue = Color.green(pixel); 

            Log.d("***RGB***", "X: "+x+" Y: "+y /*+" Green: "+greenValue*/);

            tv_selected_colour.setText(""+redValue+""+blueValue+""+greenValue);
            tv_selected_colour.setText("touched color:" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(redValue) + Integer.toHexString(greenValue) + Integer.toHexString(blueValue));

            tv_selected_colour.setTextColor(pixel);
            return false;
        }
});
```

This is my code which displays RGB color but I want to Display color name as well .. I have found this java Library https://gist.github.com/nightlark/6482130 , how can I implement this in my project .. Can anyone suggest me please ???

Comment: you need to create a local db for all colors with their RGB values and match the RGB value in the local DB.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the class to your project and call it

```
@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int x = (int) event.getX();

            int y = (int) event.getY();

            final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

            int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);

            redValue = Color.red(pixel);
            blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
            greenValue = Color.green(pixel);

            // instantiate it and call getColorName
            ColorNameLookup CNL = new ColorNameLookup();
            String name = CNL.getColorName(redValue,greenValue,blueValue);  

            Log.d("***RGB***", "X: "+x+" Y: "+y /*+" Green: "+greenValue*/);

            tv_selected_colour.setText(""+redValue+""+blueValue+""+greenValue);
            tv_selected_colour.setText("touched color:" + "#" + Integer.toHexString(redValue) + Integer.toHexString(greenValue) + Integer.toHexString(blueValue));

            tv_selected_colour.setTextColor(pixel);
            return false;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with static method like

```
public class Color{
    private static HashMap<String,String> colors;

    public static void init(){
      // add you color here
      colors = new HashMap<String,String>();
      colors.put("000000" , "white");
      // and so on
    }

    public static String getColorName(String colorValue){
       if (colors.containsKey(colorValue))
           return colors.get(colorValue);
       else return "No such Color";
    }
}
```

Call below when your activity runs.

```
Color.init();
```

Call below to get the color name

```
Color.getColorName(String.valueOf(redValue)+String.valueOf(greenValue)+String.valueOf(blueValue));
```